# What's the keyword to find hotels where the pool is heated above 27C?

Tags: hotels

As best as I can tell, hotel pools fall into 3 categories:

1. No heating / heating by solar energy alone. The water is usually around the same temperature as the air, maybe a bit warmer if there's a lot of sun.
2. Heated to standard pool temperature, around 27C.
3. Heated to a higher temperature, around 30C.

While 27C is more than enough for *swimming*, it's not enjoyable for sitting around in the pool. But I can't figure out how to find hotels in the third category, as the term "heated pool" refers to both 27C and 28+C pools, as best as I can tell. It's also not about the number of stars that a hotel has - I've seen 4-star hotels with 27C pools and 3-star hotels with 30C pools.

So far I've sometimes been able to figure it out by carefully reading the reviews and checking whether anyone complained about the water being cold, but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Do you actually measure the pool temperature or is that just your feeling? Water temperature can be extremely subjective. Also in my experience in some places the pool can be very warm one day, and the next day much cooler after a a big rainy episode.

Comment: @jcaron I don't literally carry a thermometer but the difference is *very* noticeable. 27C is a temperature where you need some convincing to get in. Around 30C it becomes warm enough that you *want* to get in.

Comment: 27C is way to high for an actual swimming workout, but not too bad for lounging around.

Comment: @JonCuster Wiki claims Olympic pools must be kept at 25-28C. Hot tubs are usually set to 37C. For slow swimming I think 30-32C is ideal but its hard to figure out the temperature in advance.

Comment: Depending on where in the world you are, there may be completely separate categories for this. Like *onsen* in Japan…

Comment: @deceze *onsens* are heated to 39C as per a quick Google search, so they're not meant for swimming.

Comment: Yeah, they’re not for swimming at all; but if you’re looking to “lounge around” for an extended time in hot water, onsen it is.

Comment: To add: in Germany and other parts of Europe, you’d be looking for a *Therme*, which usually has swimmable and hot pools.

Comment: Generally, “spa” may get you what you’re looking for, as for example here: https://soranohotel.com/en/spa/. But again, what exactly that means may substantially differ between different parts of the world.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't expect much temperature consistency from your average we-also-have-a-pool hotel pool. If you simply have a hotel which simply includes a pool, you'd probably need to contact the hotel in advance to figure out whether they place any importance on its temperate and what it's set to.

The presence of a “swim-up bar” is a good sign that it’s a pool heated to a comfortable temperature.

If you're specifically looking for a warm-to-hot bath to relax in, you'll probably want to look for places centred around this very idea, or at least hotels which offer specifically hot water pools. These may have different terms in different parts of the world.

In Europe, you'd be looking for a *thermal bath* (de: *Therme*, fr: *thermalisme*, es: *termalismo* and similar variants). These usually have swimmable warm pools and separate hot pools, in addition to saunas. You can find thermal baths to just spend a few hours to a day, and hotels build around thermal baths.

In Arabic countries (and as exports from there), you'll find [*hammam* or *Turkish baths*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammam) with similar roots.

The general international term is *spa*. Depending on the country, this may or may not focus more on massages or saunas and more or less swimming, but you'll surely find warm water there in some form. If your hotel specifically advertises a spa, you can be fairly sure it has a "loungeable" pool. More or less random example: https://soranohotel.com/en/spa/.

In some countries there may be specific local variations like [*onsen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsen), which is its own cultural thing to the degree that you specifically go there to experience it. You can again find *onsen* to dip into for an hour, and guest houses or entire towns designed around the *onsen* to spend a few days at.

Internationally similar places are generically known as *hot springs* or *hot spring resorts*, which may or may not have local cultural significance the way *onsen* have in Japan.

Comment: (+1) While the words have the same root, it's worth noting that unlike the English “spa” and maybe the German *Therme*, the French word *thermalisme* only refers to spring water in an officially recognised spa town. Anything else would be called a “spa” in French too.

Comment: Similar to the protected term *“Bad”* in Germany I guess.

Comment: A generic term that can be used in North America is "hot springs" which seems to relate to your European "thermal bath" concept.    Of course searching for "aguas calientes" in Mexico simply turns up the municipality/state of Aguascalientes rather than any specific hot springs - although the town has plenty of them.

Comment: @Peter I thought of "hot springs" in America more in terms of Yellowstone, but I suppose a "hot spring resort" is specifically what an onsen/thermal bath is in other parts of the world.

Comment: @deceze Hot springs can also simply refer to hot water bubbling up from somewhere, whether a part of a resort or simply natural - I have both in my local area. But I'd think of Yellowstone more in terms of the geysers there - which are on the extreme side of "hot", although there are human rated hot springs in the general area.

Comment: Also, in terms of hotels/resorts geared towards lingering in a pool would be those resorts that offer "swim up bars"

Comment: @Peter That’s a good one, added it.

Comment: +1 because a *hot spring*/*onsen* would always have water above 30C but there's also plenty of hotels that have a very warm pool despite not having that title.